# Entity Framework write lock on select

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Is there any way to make Entity Framework generate select queries with write lock: SELECT ... FOR UPDATE?

Comment: just wrap the select and update in transaction scope

Comment: It is not the same. Even IsolationLevel.Serializable generates SELECTs with *read* locks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first result of googling for "entity framework linq select with lock" gave the answer you want.  Check this out: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/5219035b-aaa9-4917-b2f2-852b5d8449ea/

Here's an idea though.  You can create a stored procedure where you select with lock.  Then call that stored procedure via entity framework's generated context.

Comment: Why do I need to create a stored procedure? I can just execute raw SQL. The question was about generating write-lock enabled SELECT by EF

Comment: Well, I would advise against embedded SQL.  But that's your call.  I guess I assumed that you were using LINQ to Entity, and the link in the answer will tell you that you can't do it.  But if you're embedding SQL as hard-coded strings, you're on your own, buddy.

Comment: But Kon, the link is not totally clear - specifically, it is not clear what IsolationLevel should be set to.  Care to clarify ? [I'm guessing it should be IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead ?]